# converting Year and Month varchar to date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a table with Month , Year as varchar. I realized it was a big mistake. Since its getting too 
  complicated to query this way.

```
 Year Month Productname 
      2013  11      ACB
      2013  11      CDE
```

I would now like to add another column called date and store these Year Month as a date to my existing table

```
   Year  Month   ProductName     Date
   2013   11        ACB          2013-11-01
   2013   11        CDE          2013-11-01
```

Is there a way I can do it for all the columns of the existing table ??

Please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your month and year columns to strings concatenated with '-'s and add '-01' to the end.  Then convert to a date.

```
UPDATE t
SET t.[Date] = convert(date, convert(varchar(4), 
                       t.[Year]) + '-' + convert(varchar(2), t.[Month]) + '-01')
FROM Table t
```

This will create a date for all records in your table.

Comment: If you use this method, make sure you scrub your data first.  A row with `[Month] = ' 11'` will become January, not November.  As a general rule, trying to construct dates by concatenating strings and then parsing them is an easy way to get very nasty silent bugs.  Using the constructor functions like `DATEFROMPARTS()` is much safer.

Answer (score 1):

It should just be a matter of concatenating things if I understand the problem.

For example:

```
update table1 set [date] = convert(date, month + '-01-' + year)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET [Date] = DATEFROMPARTS([Year],[Month],1)
```